# Dynamically add <select> inputs populated with database records

Tags: jquery, laravel

**Note:** Issue has been resolved, **partially**. There's now an error in the loop to generate the `<option>` elements. More info at the bottom of this post. Bounty will still be rewarded to anyone who provides a solution for this new issue.

**Note 2:** Issue has been resolved, selected solution is for the error in the loop, I posted the solution of the origin question below for completeness.

---

I'm using Laravel 5.7 with laravelcollective/html for my forms.

I'm trying to create a page where the user can create an order and add products to it. The user has to be able to press a button with a `+` sign to add more products.

The regular number input for the quantity is easy, I can just append it using jQuery like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#addMoreProducts').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#fieldList").append("<div class='col-sm-6'>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<div class='form-group'>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<label for='quantity[]'>Quantity</label>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<input class='form-control' placeholder='Quantity' name='quantity[]' type='number'>");
    $("#fieldList").append("</div>");
    $("#fieldList").append("</div>");
    $("#fieldList").append("</div>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I **can not** figure out how to add `<select>` inputs dynamically **with** the records from the database. These are the fields that I need to "duplicate".

```html
<div class="row" id="fieldList">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('product_id[]', 'Product')}}
        {{Form::select('product_id[]', $products->pluck('name', 'id'), null, ['id' => 'select2', 'class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => 'Product'])}}
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group">
       {{Form::label('quantity[]', 'Quantity')}}
       {{Form::number('quantity[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Quantity'])}}
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
    
<div class="form-group">
  <a id="addMoreProducts" class="btn btn-block btn-default">+</a>
</div>
```

Product info is passed in through the controller.

I've tried appending the `<select>` inputs as well and they display but ofcourse the options aren't in there.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#addMoreProducts').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#fieldList").append("<div class='row' id='fieldlist'>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<div class='col-sm-6'>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<div class='form-group'>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<label for='product_id[]'>Product</label>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<select id='select2' class='form-control select2' name='product_id[]'><option selected='selected' value=''>Product</option></select>");
    $("#fieldList").append("</div>");
    $("#fieldList").append("</div>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<div class='col-sm-6'>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<div class='form-group'>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<label for='quantity[]'>Quantity</label>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<input class='form-control' placeholder='Quantity' name='quantity[]' type='number'>");
    $("#fieldList").append("</div>");
    $("#fieldList").append("</div>");
    $("#fieldList").append("</div>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*How do I add additional `<select>` inputs while keeping it populated by the rows in my database?*

Not familiar with AJAX, but is this a scenario that I need it for? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is the products table:

id|name|description|product_category_id|supplier_id|sales_price|buy_price|instock|discontinued

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->mediumText('description');
        $table->integer('product_category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned();
        $table->decimal('sales_price', 8, 2);
        $table->decimal('buy_price', 8, 2);
        $table->boolean('instock');
        $table->boolean('discontinued');

        $table->foreign('product_category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Example of what the generated `<select>` should look like:

```
<select id="select2" class="form-control select2" name="product_id[]">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Product</option>
  <option value="1">Windows 10 License</option>
  <!-- etc... -->
</select>
```

---

**Partial solution:**

I'm using this code to pass the `$products` variable so it's accesible by my js file:

```
<script>
  var products = {!! json_encode($products->toArray(), JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};
</script>
```

Tested this like so, with one product in the `<select>`:

```js
/* Generate standard input */
input_select = `
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product_id[]">Product</label>
                <select id="select2" class="form-control select2" name="product_id[]">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Product</option>
`;

/* generate options */
i = 0;
input_select += "               <option value='" + products[i].id + "'>" + products[i].name + "</option>";

/* Close standard input */
input_select += `
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quantity[]">Quantity</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity[]" type="number" value="" id="quantity[]">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`;

/* append function */
$(function() {
    $('#more').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fieldlist").append(input_select);
        $('.select2').select2();
    });
});
```

This works fine and produces the desired result. **But I need to loop the generate options part.** I tried to do it like so:

```
for (var i = 0 < products.length; i++;) {
    input_select += "       <option value='" + products[i].id + "'>" + products[i].name + "</option>";
}
```

This throws the error:

> TypeError: products[i] is undefined

This is what the `products` variable contains:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I can create an AJAX code to get this data from the database directly, but just include your database tables or records, to do that ;)

Comment: and add to your question, about any code if it's work - to know more about your problem :)

Comment: I added the migration. I would only need the name and ID and loop it so that it creates a `<option>` for each one.

Comment: Please tell me, what exactly should happen? Do you click a button, for example, a data set? Please explain more :) - for example an HTML code, you want to use it to show your data - I will create an AJAX but I don't know what will I send to Database and what will I receive for your page?

Comment: When I click the button, it should create the same inputs as in the post, below the last one, with the products in my database in the `<select>`

Comment: Ok, so please add a select example - just fake options :)

Comment: Added it to the post.

Comment: Not familiar with laravel, however on the jQuery side, I can suggest that concatenating all of your html into one string and calling `.append()` just once is much more efficient than calling it a dozen times for each little piece of html. [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can really help with readability too.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into using something like this, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a data set in `products` variable? Can you show that data?

Comment: I've added an image with the contents of the variable in the console.

Comment: Can you re-check your `for` loop syntax.

Comment: The issue was there, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is on the **for** statement try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    input_select += "       <option value='" + products[i].id + "'>" + products[i].name + "</option>";
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid now haha. Thanks, this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Just going to leave the total solution here, for anyone trying to accomplish the same / something similar.**

You need to pass the data from your controller to your view and to your javascript file through a small script like this:

```
<script>
  // $products is passed in through the controller
  var products = {!! json_encode($products->toArray(), JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};
</script>
```

Then, create a javascript file and create a template literal for the input to be appended.

```
/* Generate standard input */
input_select = `
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product_id[]">Product</label>
                <select id="select2" class="form-control select2" name="product_id[]">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Product</option>
`;

/* generate options */
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    input_select += "       <option value='" + products[i].id + "'>" + products[i].name + "</option>";
}

/* Close standard input */
input_select += `
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quantity[]">Quantity</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity[]" type="number" value="" id="quantity[]">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`;

/* append function */
$(function() {
    $('#more').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fieldlist").append(input_select);

        /*
         *
         * Note: I use select2, if you don't, remove this line.
         *
         */
        $('.select2').select2();

    });
});
```

Then in your view, wrap the input that you'd like to append to in a div with the id of `#fieldlist` (or whatever you want, make sure to change it in the js file too)

```
<div id="fieldlist">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('product_id[]', 'Product')}}
        {{Form::select('product_id[]', $products->pluck('name', 'id'), null, ['id' => 'select2', 'class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => 'Product'])}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('quantity[]', 'Quantity')}}
        {{Form::number('quantity[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Quantity'])}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Finally, for the button:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <a id="more" class="btn btn-block btn-default">+</a>
</div>
```